ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'layoutparser.models'
I'm attempting to create an executable file using PyInstaller, but I encountered an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'layoutparser.models'   caused by this line of code :

model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config', extra_confi[![enter image description here][1]][1]g ["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.8],label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3: "Table", 4: "Figure"})

.
I tried to use --hidden-import but it didn't work.

I created  a new file named "hook-layoutparser.py" in hook folder with the following code : hiddenimports = ['layoutparser.models'] and it's not working. I got this error : NameError: name 'name' is not defined
the error is as shown below caused by the same line of code :

